# Spring boot applications sometimes fails to "bind properties" on high load

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

So every morning we're starting around ~30 spring-boot microservices.
Sometimes one of them is failing to start up.

**Running Spring boot 2.1.5.**

Today it was with the following error:

```
2021-11-15 02:18:32.269  INFO 12258023 --- [main] dk.yx.oiltanks.OilTanksApplication       : The following profiles are active: prod
2021-11-15 02:19:49.406 ERROR 12258023 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.mvc.servlet' to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties$Servlet:

    Reason: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.mvc.servlet' to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties$Servlet

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Is there any configuration parameters to increase "bind properties" time ?

All we did to get this application running again was starting it with the normal command.

**Configuration file:**

```
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=GET
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=**HOSTNAME**:13499/eureka/
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=https\://${eureka.hostname}\:${server.port}/actuator/health
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=https\://${eureka.hostname}\:${server.port}/
eureka.instance.hostname=**HOSTNAME**
eureka.instance.nonSecurePortEnabled=false
eureka.instance.securePort=${server.port}
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=https\://${eureka.hostname}\:${server.port}/actuator/info
feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout=1600000
feign.client.config.default.readTimeout=1600000
logging.file.max-history=50
logging.file.max-size=100MB
logging.file=application.log
logging.level.dk.yx.yxdb=INFO
logging.level.dk.yx=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=*
multipart.maxFileSize=-1
multipart.maxRequestSize=-1
pring.mvc.async.request-timeout=300000
server.connection-timeout=999999
server.http.port=3517
server.port=13517
server.ssl.key-alias=yx_dk
server.ssl.key-store-password=**PASSWORD**
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=/QOpenSys/etc/ssl/wildcard_yx_dk.p12
spring.application.name=OIL_TANK_SERVICE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.hibernate.default_schema=NHODATA
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=90000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=120000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=3
spring.datasource.password=unreadable
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:as400\:bmw/;naming\=system;libraries\=NHODATA,QTEMP,YXDTA24,ICEBREAK,NHOPRG,SYSAFD,QGPL,QIDU,OTCONLINE,SMS,YXDB,YXAPP,SMSDB;date format\=eur;time format\=eur;
spring.datasource.username=sqlread
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize=-1
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize=-1
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=999999
spring.output.ansi.enabled=DETECT
spring.profiles.active=prod
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
yx.nps.ip=**IP**
yx.nps.username=**password**
yx.project.description=Service for handling all oiltank related stuff.
```

Comment: Without the actual underlying error this will be impossible to answer. Ge the original stacktrace instead of the analyzed content so that you know where the actual issue is.

Comment: @M.Deinum How do I obtain it? Because I only get this in the log

Comment: You can run with `--debug` or set `debug=true` in your properties (this will also turn on excesive logging for the time being). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.startup-failure